# How to detect MS Office Word wordwrap in ContentControl in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a content control in word, let's call it docHeader. When the text inside that control gets long, the MSWord automatically continues from next line (wraps the text?). This causes some other controls to change their position, what I don't want.

My question is, is it possible to detect it somehow, that the control's value has multiple lines?

```
    ContentControl contControl = document.GetDocumentContentControlByName("docHeader");

    //Check if contControl.Value is longer than one line
    //Probably also depends on font size, margins, etc.

    //This is what I finally need:
    contControl.HasMultipleLines();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to snoop it to see what's inside? If it contains `TextBlock` you can just set its [`TextWrapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textwrapping(v=vs.110).aspx) to disable wrapping.

Comment: Yes I can see what's inside. But I cannot just disable wrapping. It's actually not that simple, but just for example here, I go through the document and do 10s of different validations. This is the one I have trouble. I need to give user a warning or error for every case the validation fails.